# How create multiple instances of a class object using rows and columns of dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, class, object

First time creating and using classes, so I am likely missing something obvious. Anyways, I have a class that works fine if I am providing it a single instance (sequence).

```
 class Protein(object):

    def __init__(self,sequence):
        self.peptide=sequence
        self.length=len(self.peptide)
        self.mass=int(Peptide.Mass(self.peptide))
```

I need to create >20k instances that are contained within a data frame. Here is a simplified example:

```
x= {'Gene': {0: 'Apple',
      1: 'Orange',
      2: 'Grape',
      3: 'Kiwi',
      4: 'Berry'},
     'Sequence': {0: 'TYK', 1: 'WWK', 2: 'CLK', 3: 'KVA', 4: 'VAV'},
     'UniprotID': {0: AJ38498, 1: AJ334343, 2: AJ67798, 3: AJ36998, 4: AJ15287}
}

df= pd.DataFrame(x)
```

This probably isn't the best way, but I would like to create a function that generates multiple instances of my class (Peptide) using a function. I am planning to do the same data analysis across multiple data frames (possibly with different column names), thus creating a function would save me time in the long run. Here is my attempt:

```
def Menu(df,identity,sequence,db_id):
    for protein,sequence,name in zip(df[identity],df[sequence],df[db_id]):
        protein = Protein(sequence)
        protein.name=str(name)
```

Example:

```
   Menu(df,"Gene","Sequence","UniprotID")
```

Currently, it is not creating the instance:

```
##If I type Kiwi.mass it will return an error stating that the object Kiwi doesn't exist.
```

Comment: an explanation for a downvote? I understand my problem seems better solved by applying a function row-wise, but classes allow me to produce additional attributes automatically. Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Menu` functions doesnt seem to be returning anything, also, it's overwriting the protein object in the `for` loop.

So, for what you are asking, in your `Menu` function you might create an empty list and fill in in your `for` loop and return that list.

```
def Menu(df,identity,sequence,db_id):
    proteins = []
    for protein,sequence,name in zip(df[identity],df[sequence],df[db_id]):
        protein = Protein(sequence)
        protein.name=str(name)
        proteins.append(protein)

    return proteins
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give this shot. I avoided creating a list, because I don't understand how I would be able to call the object without call the list first. Again, speaking before trying...I will give this a go.

Comment: Well, I would suggest avoiding the creation of the list from the dataframe and perform the operations directly in the dataframe, given that as your dataframe gets  larger, you'll need to create more and more objects; so you will have the same data both in the dataframe and in the list. So maybe just perform the operations directly row-wise in the dataframe, for better performance.

Comment: I suppose that is another way around this. I was hoping to be able to call each instance in other functions which use other dataframes with overlapping columns (i.e. Kiwi). My current functions do this, but objects just seemed cleaner in code. Thanks again!.